# C# - using XmlNode class to find acroform or xfa form

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

I am making use of Xmlnode class to find acroform or xfa form i am thinking the difference as to be something in the xml content what i am trying to find out is the template node

so for example i get the xml i want to make use of this class to find out

```
"template" node
```

if "template" node is there i want to print a message concerning template part and if it is not there i will print some other message

I have reached this far:

```
private void getFormType(string reasonstring)
{      
    XmlDocument docxml = new XmlDocument();
    docxml.LoadXml(reasonstring);
    System.Xml.XmlNode xmlNode = docxml.SelectSingleNode("xml");           
}
```

Comment: Can you add your input xml to the question?